# Another php nested loop

Tags: php

How can I print this output using a FOR - NESTED loop using PHP?

It's not really helpful for me getting ready code, I want to understand how to reach this result using 2 for loops.

```
5
54
543
5432
54321
```

Comment: Is one for loop okay as well?

Comment: Is it necessary to downvote a question that looks like a school assignment?

Comment: @Salman A I have no idea. I didn't down vote this question. Perhaps the down voter could explain their purpose.

Comment: @Treffynnon: I did not either though I upvoted your comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's not a particularly good question. There should be at least SOME work shown (what approach have you tried so far?). If you don't even know where to start, you may want to read up on the very basics of PHP and programming first.

Answer (score 2):

```
for($i=5; $i>=1; $i--)
{
  for($j=5; $j>=$i; $j--)
  {
    echo $j;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well a general way to solve loop problems is writing your code linear at first, without loops

So, write 5 loops first, each printing one line.
Then try to find some regularity in them and combine in one

Answer (score -2):

With one for loop. I don't see any reason to have two loops. If there is a reason beyond this being an assignment then please explain that reason in your question.

```
$str = '';
for($i = 5; $i > 0; $i--) {
   $str .= $i;
   echo $str . "\n";
}
```

Comment: When down voting on SO it is customary to give a reason for your down votes. What is wrong with this answer beside it being a more efficient answer to the question?